# How do I have JavaScript target an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page with **2 iframes** and i was wondering if it was possible to have a link in the parent window that affects the iframe.

I know how to make a normal link that changes the page in the iframe but I need to make I, that it activates JavaScript into the iframe.

```
// The JS | normally in one line
javascript:var%20KICKASSVERSION='2.0';
var%20s%20=%20document.createElement('script');
s.type='text/javascript';document.body.appendChild(s);
s.src='//hi.kickassapp.com/kickass.js';
void(0);
```

If you put that into an address bar it works without changing the page but I was wondering if this is possible in an iframe. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me if you want to: 1. get the content of the iframe 2. change the content of the iframe, 3. change the linked html page of the iframe.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner but I have been busy with work. I wish to do none of those things. All i want to do is activate some javascript into the iframe. I am pretty sure you can do it with flash too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, the easiest way to do this would be to do something like this:

```
var iframe=/*DOM REFERENCE TO YOUR IFRAME, for example:*/document.getElementById('myIframe');
iframe.src="javascript:var%20KICKASSVERSION='2.0';var%20s%20=%20document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';document.body.appendChild(s);s.src='//hi.kickassapp.com/kickass.js';void(0);";
```

However, a more clean approach would be something like:

```
var myLink=document.getElementById('myLink');

myLink.addEventListener('click',function(evt){
 var myFrame=document.getElementById('myFrame');
 var win=myFrame.contentWindow;

 win.KICKASSVERSION='2.0';
 var s = win.document.createElement('script');
 s.type='text/javascript';win.document.body.appendChild(s);
 s.src='//hi.kickassapp.com/kickass.js';

 evt.preventDefault();
}
```

Please note that in all cases the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) is enforced.

Answer (score 1):

HTML iframes have a `contentDocument` property (see [the MDN page on iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLIFrameElement)) that allow you to manipulate the inner document of an iframe.

Rough guidelines (untested, but you get the idea :)):

```
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.contentDocument.location.href = "..."; // change the inner iframe's location
iframe.contentDocument.body.appendChild(yourScriptNode); // append a script inside the iframe
```